# OpenSSL Private Key Error when creating P12 Certificate

Tags: openssl

I am trying to create a P12 certificate from some existing .der files that were created from OpenSSL.

When I tried running the command below, I got an error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>openssl pkcs12 -export -out bundle.p12 -inkey <PATH>/PrivKey.der -in <PATH>/ClientSignedCert.der -certfile <PATH>/CACert.der
```

The error I received:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
unable to load private key
5688:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib
.c:696:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I don't understand this.  I am giving OpenSSL a private key (PrivKey.der). What could be the cause of this error?

OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012)
Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 4):

According to the openssl PKCS12 documentation, your `-in`, `-inkey` and certfile files has to be in PEM format.

To convert a certificate from DER to PEM:

```
x509 –in ClientSignedCert.der –inform DER –out ClientSignedCert.crt –outform PEM
x509 –in CACert.der –inform DER –out CACert.crt –outform PEM
```

To convert a key from DER to PEM:

```
rsa –in PrivKey.der –inform DER –out PrivKey.key –outform PEM
```

[Openssl PKCS12 documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html)